Regarding relative compactness in baby rudin
I am an early undergraduate student, self-studying baby rudin.
I have encountered a problem in Thm. $2.33$, it states that:

Suppose $K \subset Y \subset X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and
only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$.

I thought of a counterexample to this theorem, which is described below:
Let $\{a_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a monotonically increasing convergent sequence.
Let $X=\{a_k|\ k\geq1\}$ be a metric space.
Consider a finite subsequence of points $\{a_k\}_{1\leq k\leq M}$. Call the set of those points as $S$.
Consider a subset $\Gamma:=\{a_k|\ m\leq k\leq M\}\subset S;\ m\geq 1.$
Also consider a collection of subsets $\{S_n\}$, where, for a fixed $t,\ S_t:=\{a_k|\ t\leq k\leq M\};\ t\geq 1.$
Observe that each set of the collection $\{S_n\}$ is open relative to $S$ but not open relative to $X$. Let's consider a subset $S_t$, for each $p\in S_t,\ \exists\ r>0$ s.t. $q\in S_t$  whenever $d(p,q)<r, q\in S$. For a pt. $p=a_j,\ $ here $r=d(a_j,a_{j+1})+\epsilon \  \forall t\leq j\leq M-1.$ For the point $a_M,\ r:=d(a_M,a_{M-1})+\epsilon,\ $where $0< \epsilon<\delta$ for any arbitrary $\delta>0$.
And this set is not open relative to $X$ because there is no associated $r>0$ for point $a_M$.
Now, one can cover the subset $\Gamma$ using a finite collection of open covers, i.e. the set $\{S_t|\ m\leq t\leq M-1\}.$
So, $\Gamma$ is compact relative to $S$ but not relative to $X$.
This provides a counterexample to the theorem.
Where has my idea gone wrong? Please help me find it.
Also I feel that I haven't understood compactness in its correct terms as one more doubt arise in my mind that why only closed subset are compact. Can't a single open ball(which is an open subset relative to X(say, $\mathbb{R}))\ \mathrm{B}(a;r)\subseteq X$ cover any bounded open set in $X$, for "big enough" $r>0.$
Thanks in adv.

To your final question: the definition of compactness requires that any open cover contains a finite subcover, not just that there exists a finite cover (any space trivially satisfies this: just consider a singleton cover consisting of the entire space).

What do you mean “let $X$ be a metric space?” What is the metric? You have just given a set.

@Malady Judging from context, presumably the one inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

@Malady Same as pointed out by Jiang.

Yes, your counterexample does not quite work. You claim that $\Gamma$ is not compact relative to $X$, but it is. This is easy to see: $\Gamma$ is finite. Being a finite set, any topology on $\Gamma$ (including the one it inherits from $X$) must be finite. Therefore, any open cover of $\Gamma$ is itself finite.

So, you are saying that $\Gamma$ is compact rel. to $X$ because it is finite. But, can you present me any open cover with appropriate finite subcover?

@P_oly_math see if you can show that any finite space is compact with any topology. It’s an easy proof.

@P_oly_math Pick any open cover for $\Gamma$. It is itself finite.

@K.Jiang Can you give me an example of an open cover to $\Gamma$?

@P_oly_math Sure. One such is ${\Gamma \cap B_d (x, \varepsilon) | x \in \Gamma }$, where $\varepsilon = \min_{x, y \in \Gamma} {d (x, y)}$.

Note that this cover consists of singletons; i.e., it is equal to ${{x} | x \in \Gamma}$. But since $\Gamma$ is finite, so is the cover.

@K.Jiang But how are the singleton sets open subsets of $X$ as there is no associated $r>0$ for which $q\in \ $(the singleton set) whenever $d(p,q)<r,\ q\in X$.

@P_oly_math Don't forget that you are taking intersections of the balls with $\Gamma$.

Strictly speaking, the singleton sets are not open in $X$, but they do constitute an open cover of $\Gamma$ under the subspace topology. If you do not want to work with the subspace topology, you can just consider the collection ${B_d (x , \varepsilon) | x \in \Gamma}$ (with $\varepsilon$ defined as before), which is a set of open subsets of $X$ that covers $\Gamma$.
